# Content Security Policy breaks rails error pages in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy

I have content security policy enabled in my Rails application. When I run it locally in development environment the rails error pages are broken because inline JavaScript and CSS are blocked by browser's content security policy. I get the following error in Google Chrome from turbo.es2017-esm.js:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' localhost:3000 'nonce-vJgPXpdJcQ60SidkuK6V/Q=='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-N8P082RH9sZuH82Ho7454s+117pCE2iWh5PWBDp/T60='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

[image: Content security policy error]

When I inspect the page in Google Chrome, I see the `script` elements with empty `nonce` attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-template="error_page" nonce="">
```

This is probably why the javascript is blocked, since the script tags do not have the correct nonce. Is there a way to fix this?

#### `config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb`

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # The policies are set in config/environments/[development/test/production].rb

  # Generate random nonce that will be used in <script> and <style> elements
  config.content_security_policy_nonce_generator = -> (request) { SecureRandom.base64(16) }

  # Add the nonce to the Content-Security-Policy header
  config.content_security_policy_nonce_directives = %w(script-src style-src)
end
```

#### `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.default_src :self
  policy.img_src :self, 'data:'
  policy.script_src  :self
  policy.style_src   :self
  policy.connect_src :self
end
```

### Versions

Rails: 7.0.4.2 turbo-rails: 1.3.3

Javascript: @hotwired/turbo-rails: 7.2.5 @hotwired/turbo: 7.2.5 @hotwired/stimulus: 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error at another line (:348) of `turbo.es2017-esm.js`.

The solution was removing a style attribute that I had overlooked from a form field of that particular form and moving it into a proper CSS class.

Since with `turbo-rails` on it did not show the exact source of the problem. Disabling it helped, so the that the browser CSP error pointed to the right line instead of the `turbo.es2017-esm.js`.